# Build only a single .deb from apt-get source (that generates multiple .deb files)?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, debuild

Let's say I want to build a package like `network-manager`; I can do, say, on 14.04 trusty:

```
apt-get source network-manager
cd network-manager-0.9.8.8
debuild -us -uc
```

... this, however, gives me a bunch of `.deb` files when it is done, such as:

```
gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.4_amd64.deb
libnm-glib4_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.4_amd64.deb
libnm-glib-dev_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.4_amd64.deb
libnm-glib-vpn1_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.4_amd64.deb
libnm-glib-vpn-dev_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.4_amd64.deb
libnm-util2_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.4_amd64.deb
libnm-util-dev_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.4_amd64.deb
network-manager_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.4_amd64.deb
network-manager-dbg_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.4_amd64.deb
network-manager-dev_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.4_amd64.deb
```

Say I want to build **only** `network-manager_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.4_amd64.deb` - is there a `debuild` (or `dpkg-buildpackage`) switch that would allow me to do that?

Comment: I doubt it. Until the last step of actually creating the packages, `debuild` can't be sure what's going to be in them. Any of the intermediate rules could change the files. And if you have reached that step, you might as well build the whole thing and delete the others.

Comment: Thanks for that @muru - feel free to post that as an answer, I'll accept it!